# c++ initialization of an array of string pointers

Tags: c++

I want to initialize an array of `std::string` pointers of size that i get from a constructor. Also, i want to do the same for two `int` arrays but the code below doesn't compile:

```
class MyQuickInitArray
{
public:
    MyQuickInitArray(int size)
    {
        if(size <= 0)
        {
            throw new std::exception;
        }

        _size = size;
        _counter = 0;
        A = new std::string[size];
        B = new int[size];
        C = new int[size];
    }

    std::string& operator[](int j) {
        if(j > _size)
        {
            throw std::out_of_range("out of range");
        }

        if(((B[j]<0) || (B[j]>=_counter)) || (C[B[j]]!=j))
        {
            // A[j] points to junk
            _counter++;
            A[j] = new std::string;
            B[j] = _counter-1;
            C[_counter-1] = j;
            return A[j];
        }

        // the cell was instantiated before
        return A[j];
    }

    ~MyQuickInitArray(){};


private:
    std::string* A[];
    int B[];
    int C[];
    int _size;
    int _counter;
};
```

How can i properly declare an array of size that i get from a ctor?

**EDIT:**

The error that occurs is:

```
incompatible types in assignment of ‘std::string* {aka std::basic_string<char>*}’ to ‘std::string* [0]
```

And for the `int` arrays:

```
incompatible types in assignment of ‘int*’ to ‘int [0]’
```

Comment: "doesn't compile" is not enough. Also you should use `std::vector`

Comment: *code below doesn't compile* You could help us by giving the errors as well .

Comment: Use `std::vector`. Seriously. It would get rid of 80% of your code.

Comment: Do you want an array of integers or an array of an array of integers for `A` and `B`?

Comment: @Mario array of integers

Comment: Forget about the pointers and the array. Use `std::vector<std::string>`. It will make your life way easier.

Comment: @juanchopanza making vector<std::string> will initialize the whole array. The whole point of this exercise is to avoid that

Comment: It will initialize almost nothing. Certainly less variables than what you initialize in your class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not valid way of declaring static arrays in C++, array size needs to be known at compile time. Below code can't compile in standard C++ without some special extension.

```
std::string* A[];
int B[];
int C[];
```

If you are just playing with pointers that's fine. **However, you'd better think of using `std::vector`**

```
#include <vector>
std::vector<std::string> A;
std::vector<int> B;
std::vector<int> C;
```

I may rewrite your code to below:

```
class MyQuickInitArray
{
public:
    MyQuickInitArray(int size)
      : A(size),
        B(size),
        C(size),
        size_(size),
        counter_(0)
    {     
    }

    std::string operator[](int j) const 
    {
        return A.at(j);
    }

private:
    std::vector<std::string> A;
    std::vector<int> B;
    std::vector<int> C;
    int size_;
    int counter_;
};
```

Comment: -1: Why on earth would you advice `std::string* A;` that is plainly bad advice.

Comment: @AlokSave I do ask in my answer that if he's practicing pointer or not. Also I suggest use vector for A,B,C

Comment: @AlokSave I've removed anything relative to `std::string* A;` :)

Comment: +1: This is the right answer. But I'm curious – Wath happen if size<0? It get converted to size_t and we end with huge arrays (vectors) ?

Comment: @qPCR4vir vector starts with size 0, concern is actually size < 0

Comment: @billz: thank, but why 0? We explicitly initialice : A(size), ... ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use `std::vector<std::string>` or  `std::vector<int>` instead your array members. The whole code will be simpler.

But if you really want to use the arrays then you could try (Not that I recommended):

```
class MyQuickInitArray
{
public:
    MyQuickInitArray(int size):_size(0),_counter(0),A(nullptr),B(nullptr),C(nullptr)
    {
        if(size <= 0)
        {
            throw new std::exception;
        }

        _size = size;

        typedef std::string* pSTR;
        A = new pSTR[size];
        B = new int[size];
        C = new int[size];
    }

    std::string& operator[](int j) {
        if(j > _size)
        {
            throw std::out_of_range("out of range");
        }

        if(((B[j]<0) || (B[j]>=_counter)) || (C[B[j]]!=j))
        {
            // A[j] points to junk
            _counter++;
            A[j] = new std::string;
            B[j] = _counter-1;
            C[_counter-1] = j;
            return *A[j];
        }

        // the cell was instantiated before
        return *A[j];
    }

            ~MyQuickInitArray(){
               for(int j=0; j<_size; ++j)
                   if(((B[j]<0) || (B[j]>=_counter)) || (C[B[j]]!=j))
                      delete A[j];                       
               delete[]A; delete[]B; delete[]C;};
            }


private:
    std::string** A;
    int *B;
    int *C;
    int _size;
    int _counter;
};
```